# Calling update hook on returned axios call

Tags: reactjs

I have a modularized React file with a context and hooks that I want to be accessed after a successful axios POST request is made to store the resulting JSON  values. I thought simply importing this function and then passing the resulting JSON blob would update the hook state, but it appears this in the inappropriate way to call it. I couldn't find documentation matching my use case and was wondering what was wrong with this setup and how it should be performed correctly.

**Here is the error:**

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

**Here is my modularized context and hook file (AppSession.js):**

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react'

export const SessionContext = createContext(null);

const AppSession = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({ 'authenticated': false, 'user_id': '', 'user_email': '' })

    return (
        <SessionContext.Provider value={{user, setUser}}>
            {children}
        </SessionContext.Provider>
    )

}

export const getUserState = () => {
    const { user } = useContext(SessionContext)
    return user;
}

export const updateUserState = () => {
    const { setUser } = useContext(SessionContext)
    
    return (user) => {
        setUser(user);
    }
}

export default AppSession;
```

**Here is my axios call and where I try to run the update hook:**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react'
import { updateUserState, getUserState }  from '../contexts/AppSession'
import Layout from '../components/Universal/Layout';

class SignIn extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      email: null,
      password: null
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.signIn = this.signIn.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange({ target }) {
    this.setState({
      [target.name]: target.value
    });
  }

  signIn(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Axios: signIn Triggered')
    axios.post(
      '/api/auth/signin/',
      {
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password
      }
    ).then((res) => {
      console.log(res)
      const data = res.data;
      console.log("updateUserState")
      updateUserState(data)
      console.log("getUserState")
      console.log(getUserState())
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Layout 
      title="Signin"
      description="TEST"
    >
      <form method='post' action='/api/auth/signin'>
        <label>
          Username
          <input name='email' type='text' value={ this.state.email } onChange={ this.handleChange }/>
        </label>
        <label>
          Password
          <input name='password' type='text' value={ this.state.password } onChange={ this.handleChange } />
        </label>
        <button type='submit' onClick={ this.signIn }>Sign in</button>
      </form>
      </Layout>    
    )
  }
}

export default SignIn;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, I suggest you should choose one approach, hooks or class components. here you are mixing two different approaches, that's not the way to go.

about this error, happens because you called the hook at the `signin` function. you can only call hooks at the body of a function component, not by another function nested at function body.

also `updateUserState` doesn't take params on first invoke, it returns another function, and that function receives data and update user state.

though I don't see point in creating those context functions, it's somewhat redudant. I would suggest to import useContext and SessionContext to expose `user` and `setUser` at given interested component, that's the common approach.

below I refactored your Login component to hooks, where it should be working:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { SessionContext }  from '../contexts/AppSession'
import Layout from '../components/Universal/Layout';

const SignIn = () => {
  const [{ email, password }, setForm] = useState({ email: null, password: null })
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(SessionContext) // here you are calling a hook at component body

  const handleChange = ({ target }) => {
    setForm( prevForm => ({
      ...prevForm,
      [target.name]: target.value
    }));
  }

  const signIn = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Axios: signIn Triggered')
    axios.post(
      '/api/auth/signin/',
      { email, password } // you don't need to do email: email when key and value have same naming
    ).then((res) => {
      console.log(res)
      const data = res.data;
      console.log("updateUserState")
      setUser(data)
      // you can't console log updated user data here, you should use a useEffect for that
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(user)
  }, [user]) // with that console.log will run on every user change

    return (
      <Layout 
      title="Signin"
      description="TEST"
      >
        <form method='post' action='/api/auth/signin'>
          <label>
            Username
            <input name='email' type='text' value={ email } onChange={ handleChange }/>
          </label>
          <label>
            Password
            <input name='password' type='text' value={ password } onChange={ handleChange } />
          </label>
          <button type='submit' onClick={ signIn }>Sign in</button>
        </form>
      </Layout>    
    )
}

export default SignIn;
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer! This has definitely been a topic that has confused me as I have learned it and the nesting aspect is something that I completely missed. In terms of class vs functions, no need to update the answer, but what would change? (Link to resource would be enough). Hooks are only used for functions right? A component would directly use the state from a constructor function? Also the one edit I would make is removing `useState` from the `AppSession` import and moving that to the `react` import

Comment: fixed useState import, thank you for pointing out :) yes, hooks are used to be called only on function components. it's another approach, different from class components. it's way less verbose overall. the first question It would be regarding if I had pick class over hooks to implement context? well you can find the docs here and have some examples with classes https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context.